# Is there any way to use Auth0 in ASP.NET web forms page application?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, auth0

I was trying to implement Auth0 in the web forms page (aspx) application and the documentation on link https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet seems to be deleted as it redirects to other quickstarts for Regular Web Apps. I tried using ASP.NET (OWIN) i.e. MVC documentation but that doesn't seem to be working. So my question is that is it still possible to implement Auth0 in traditional webforms apps?

Comment: If you scroll down on the page that lists all the quick starts, [there is one for OWIN](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/webapi-owin). It's meant for Web API, but it may still meet your needs, as the middleware setup should still apply. You'd just skip the controller part of the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can but you have to take the help of asp.net MVC.

Asp.NET MVC is built on top of ASP.NET so, we can easily integrate webform applications and take the benfit of MVC controllers and route config classes.

For this, you need to include the below packages.

```
 //for mvc
Microsoft.AspNet.mvc

//for owin
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
```

Create two folders at root level,

```
    a. App_Start and,
    b. Controllers same as an MVC project.
```

The file content of the folder should be as follow:

```
1. App_Start folder - add the below class files.
 a. RouteConfig.cs - 
      Here we will set up the default route to Home/index. Thus, any 
        redirection (“/”) or http://localhost, will redirect to the 
       home/index, which will in turn call the authentication method.

 b. Startup.cs - It will be the Owin startup class. 
    This can also be used to write custom middleware.

2. Controllers - add the below controllers

    a. Home - decorate *[Authorize]* attribute at controller 
       level. Add a default index action. Call the action that will 
       implement authentication logic. In this case, AccountController.

    b. Account - where you will write code for authentication.
```

Whenever session is out, you can simply redirect to Home/index from any .aspx.cs page by writing below code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     if (Session["CurrentUser"] == null) {        
         Response.Redirect("/");
     }

   // other logics
   // ---
   // ---

   
  }
```